# how to deal with hundreds of colums data from textfile when training a model using spark ml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a textfile with hundreds of columns , but the columns don't have column names.

The first column is the label and the others are features. I've read some examples that must specify cloumn names for the train data. But it is quite troublesome to specify all the names since there are too many columns.

how can I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VectorAssempler` in combination with `list comprehension` to structure your data for model training. Consider this example data with two feature columns (`x1` and `x2`) and a response variable `y`.

```
df = sc.parallelize([(5, 1, 6),
                     (6, 9, 4),
                     (5, 3, 3),
                     (4, 4, 2),
                     (4, 5, 1),
                     (2, 2, 2),
                     (1, 7, 3)]).toDF(["y", "x1", "x2"])
```

First, we create a list of column names that are not `"y"`:

```
colsList = [x for x in df.columns if x!= 'y']
```

Now, we can use `VectorAssembler`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

vectorizer = VectorAssembler()
vectorizer.setInputCols(colsList)
vectorizer.setOutputCol("features")

output = vectorizer.transform(df)
output.select("features", "y").show()
+---------+---+
| features|  y|
+---------+---+
|[1.0,6.0]|  5|
|[9.0,4.0]|  6|
|[3.0,3.0]|  5|
|[4.0,2.0]|  4|
|[5.0,1.0]|  4|
|[2.0,2.0]|  2|
|[7.0,3.0]|  1|
+---------+---+
```